# PHP File Upload without refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am working on a PHP application that asks users to upload a CSV file, then inserts the CSV file records into the database and finally deletes the file. Everything is working fine. Only problem is there are multiple JQuery tabs on my page with 'Upload CSV' being one of the many tabs. Hence I'd like to upload a file without page getting refreshed, because when it refreshes the current tab loses focus and the default tab opens up.

What could be the best possible solution in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

Us this : http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing.
Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Upload file using JQuery itself or add some hidden input in your upload form that will have value of opened tab id and after refresh set focus on that tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload.php",
    success: function()
    {
        alert("uploaded");
    }
});
```